# Codelite 9.2 indentation configuration

Tags: formatting, ide, indentation, codelite

CodeLite is a cool analogue to Visual Studio. 
But I faced indentation issue: when I write for instance function declaration I want to declare it's body like this:

```
   void doSmth()
   {

   }
```

But with CodeLite I get this:

```
   void doSmth()
   {
          }
```

Please advise how do I handle it.
Visual explanation as follows. Please click on the link

[CodeLite indentation behaviour.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeVa9.png)
P.S.: I tried to configure it through Settings->Preferences->Editor->Indentation and disabled Smart Indentation. When cursor is between braces and I hit "Enter" the lower brace is just moved in the beginning of the new line, but not under the upper brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't type the closing paren. CodeLite will add and indent the code for you.

Also, you can use `Ctrl-I` to indent an existing code (see: `Plugins->Source Code Formatter` for more details)

```
void doSmth()
{ // Hit ENTER here without the closing paren
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked for me. Detail but pleasant:D